# How can I append LinkedIn share title?

Tags: html, linkedin-api, sharing

I'm using jQuery to get the main title part but I want to add some custom text at the end of the title. I'm pretty much convinced that I've messed something with the apostrophes but I can't figure out where.

The text I want to add is "CUSTOM SHARE TEXT".

This is where I'm stuck:

```
    <a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=' + jQuery('.active-review').attr('href') + '&title=' + jQuery('.active-review .head-container').text() + 'CUSTOM SHARE TEXT', '', '_blank, width=500, height=500, resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes'); return false;">
    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-linkedin"></i> LinkedIn</a>
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was in excessive spaces in jQuery component. After adding `trim()` function, the problem seems to be resolved in my case. The text appended to a title was always here but was not visible due to dozens of `%20`after the title.

Here is the final code that works for me.

```
    <a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=' + encodeURIComponent(document.URL) + '&title=' + encodeURIComponent(jQuery('.active-review .head-container').text().trim()) + encodeURIComponent(' CUSTOM TEXT'),'', '_blank, width=500, height=500, resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes'); return false;"
        ><i class="fa fa-fw fa-linkedin"></i> LinkedIn</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is related to spaces and other invalid characters in the URL.

You should always use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) when building URLs from text.

Also, as you correctly stated, you forgot some apostrophes.

Try this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=' + encodeURIComponent(jQuery('.active-review').attr('href')) + '&title=' + encodeURIComponent(jQuery('.active-review .head-container').text()) + encodeURIComponent('CUSTOM SHARE TEXT'), '', '_blank', 'width=500, height=500, resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes'); return false;">
    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-linkedin"></i> LinkedIn
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the `encodeURIComponent` suggestion! But the custom text is still not showing up when sharing, only the main title. I've been trying to solve this for a couple of hours now - going crazy!

Comment: Please post a URL that works (written by hand), so I can compare it with your code.